# Connect Solr to database managed by SQL Management Studio

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Currently I access my database instance via sql management studio, and the structure is something like:

SQL Server, database, database instance, table I care about.

I wish to use solr to index this data, but I cannot seem to connect to the server sucsessfully.

I have the following as my `data-config.xml`:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
          driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
          url="jdbc:sqlserver://mySQLServer/DEV1"
          integratedSecurity="true"
          database="someData"
/>
<document>
    <entity name="myQuery" query="select * from temp_ip_solr_test"
            deltaQuery="select id from item where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
        <field column="NAME" name="name" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

Everything else is standard (though I did add the jdbc .jar file, and the sqlauth .dll file to the lib of the db core (that is the one that I am using), right out of the `example-DIH` example that is given with solr.

The error is:
`Exception while processing: myQuery document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select * from temp_ip_solr_test Processing Document # 1`

The only warning is: `SimplePropertiesWriter Unable to read: dataimport.properties`

How can I make this work?

Solr version 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to integrated security mechanism..

check this link for more details:http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-SQL-Express-Integrated-Security-Unable-to-execute-query-td4035758.html

Try providing username and password explicitly and check if it works...

The below config file works fine with sql server. Make sure you are using the correct database / server name.

```
<dataConfig>  
      <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
            driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;databaseName=mydb;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor"   
            user="sa" 
            password="password"/>  
      <document>  
        <entity name="results" query="SELECT statements">  
          <field column="fielda" name="fielda"/>
    <field column="fieldb" name="fieldb"/>
    <field column="fieldc" name="fieldc"/>  
        </entity>  
      </document>  
    </dataConfig>
```

Comment: Mind explaining the databaseName=mydb? Is the parameter really called databaseName?

Comment: Its one of the properties of SQL JDBC server driver. Check out the properties here..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

Comment: And it didn't even show up in the profiler as a failed attempted at logon

Comment: Can you paste the complete stack trace?

Comment: How did you capture the above error? The stack trace should be in logs.

Comment: so it is the login that fails. I am working on seeing how I can get integrative servfices to work

Comment: I would suggest you to make sure if your issue gets fixed when specifying username and password explicitly before working on resolving the next issue..

Comment: Integrated security is probably not going to work. My guess for how it might would be that you need to setup your Solr instance on a Windows server and have the JNDI Container(Jetty, Tomcat, etc.) running under a domain level account that has appropriate access to the SQL Server database. This may or may not work. Otherwise I would try to use SQL Server Authentication, I know that works, like @Learner, I have done it before.